# Reasoning between environment from express and dotenv

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dotenv

I've been seeing a lot of NodeJS and `dotenv` tutorials and articles where they define an `ENV_MODE=development` variable within the `config.env` file.

But `require('express').get('env')` already gives us the environment express is set on running. Why not just use the express `env` variable to check the environment mode? Why do we need to also set the explicit variable in the `.env` file?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the environment variable **somewhere**.

Doing it in a `.env` file ties it to a specific computer, which means you don't have to either:

- Remember to set it manually before you run the program
- Bind it into package.json and risk running the wrong command when you run the code on staging/qa/production

… and it lets you keep it with any other environment variables you have (such as API keys) which shouldn't be committed to version control (since they are secrets).

Comment: So there's no problem ignoring the Express built-in environment variable? Even when it's in production, can I rely solely on the `dotenv` logic?